# Is this ok if I write a peer 2 peer apps using select() server without using fork(), thread, shared memory, semaphores?

Tags: c, sockets, semaphore, shared-memory, p2p

I'm writing a peer 2 peer chat which includes client part and server part in a same file. Currently, I'm using `select()` server and don't use `fork()`, thread, shared memory, semaphores to handle concurrency(I just use `select()` to distinguish between sockets of clients and servers).

Since I just create one process per time I start my app, let say my app named P2P. I start one peer(including a client and a server) by `./P2P PortofServer PortServerofPeerIconnect IPAddress`. In while loop, I use `select()` to wait connection from clients for server part. And client part will connect to server part of other peers every time I start a peer.

Is it possible not to use `fork()`, thread and only use `select()` to write a peer 2 peer chat? Thanks very much.

Comment: The fork model is obsolete. In fact, even select is considered inferior compared to more modern async IO. Consider using a library like boost asio or libevent.

Comment: Hi usr, I would like to confirm that is it ok if I use select() server approach without using fork(), thread, shared memory, semaphore. If I don't use fork(), thread, do I need to use shared memory, semaphore? Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: I think you should understand what these calls and techniques do before you use them. It sounds like you do not understand them and are relying on recipes to cook up a program. You won't be successful.

Comment: Hi, usr. Thanks for your comment. However, I want to know if I do this select() server approach, are there any difficulties to handle in connections in the future since client and server are written in the same file.

Comment: zuhakasa, the fork model is neither obsolete nor inferior but one tool  in the toolbox.  If you don't multitask in one way or the other (i.e. multiple processes or threads) you probably won't have a need for shared memory or synchronization.  But your basic question is unaswerable.  Select on its own will work fine up to some point but sooner or later you may hit either scaling or code complexity issues.  Whether you bite the bullet now or later is something only you can answer depending on how you envision your project growing.

Comment: My point is this: You are starting a fresh project. Why not chose the most modern approach available? Neither fork nor select are it. Fork is inflexible and architecturally very questionable. Select is not scalable (and scalability is the only reason you would use async IO). The modern epoll/kqueue approaches don't have these issues. Use an abstraction library on top of them.

Comment: I do most of my servers using select() and a single thread -- no forking or pthreads necessary.  It works fine as long as you don't need to support more than a couple hundred sockets at the same time.  The benefit is that the program's behavior becomes much easier to control/predict when there is only a single thread of execution to deal with.  The downside is that you will want to use non-blocking I/O, which is a little tricker to deal with (e.g. you have to keep state variables around to track the state of partial recv()'s and send()'s)

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comment, Jeremy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whatever the way you choose for interacting with OS (`select()` or as suggested in the comments libevent, `epoll()`, kqueue, or even boost::asio if c++ is an acceptable solution), [asynchronous mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchronous_I/O) will allow you to process everything in a single thread if implemented correctly and nothing blocks the main dispatching loop.

So yes, it is possible if you use all your IO in the asynchronous mode. But be prepared that reads & writes can be terminated at the middle of the string/packet or you'll be blocked if `select()` says the socket is not ready for the required operation (including `write`). All the new connections (sockets) to the server and user input from console (I guess, since it's a chat program) must go through `select()` (or other event dispatching mechanism).

Comment: Hi Anton, can you please tell me when select() says the socket is not ready for the required operation? If I choose select(), does this mean  sockets are kept open when there is no communication happening, doesn't it? But if I use fork() or thread instead, I can close the socket after the child or sub-threads finish their communication. Thanks very much for your comment.

Comment: @zuhakasa, `select` marks file descriptors (handles) as ready to read or ready to write or having an exception. Use FD_ISSET as described in `man select` to find out what `select` tries to tell you. A socket must be kept open until you need it for communication, then close it when not needed or when other side closed the connection. It's all the same way as with `fork` or threads.